# Panning is not responsive in D3 v5 with Collapsable Tree

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to replicate http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762 in D3 v5. In my replica, the panning responsiveness is much slower, and I am not sure why.

Here is how responsive it should be:

[image]

Here is my replica:

[image]

I am new to D3, so any general ideas on where the problem may lie? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it may be related to your transition settings (duration, delay, ease), but would need to see code to confirm

Comment: I don't think so. I replicated a very simple example of moving a circle around and faced the same issue. My theory is that it has something to do with the ReactJS + D3 combination. I can replicate it successfully without using React components.